# Pypi simple.html missing in artifactory remote repository

Tags: artifactory, remote-repository

I've setup a remote pypi repository on an artifactory v7.x
I've cached a few packaged thru that remote repository in order to move that whole installation into an isolated network.

However, I can't see artifactory generating `simple.html` as I was expecting to build a local offline index.

I've tried to setup `Metadata Retrieval Cache Period` to zero and zap the cache but that didn't solved my issue.

Am I missing something here or expecting something that isn't true?

Comment: Do you found some solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to resolve a sample file through Artifactory's PyPI remote repository and observed the expected HTML file to have been created as expected.

> (base) ➜  ~ pip install hello-pi
> Looking in indexes: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-remote/simple
> Collecting hello-pi
> Downloading http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-remote/packages/packages/35/80/c2c5e403ce35e5dbf1f8ab910d64fa111f238ae559a5ffbdd6f2288cef34/hello_pi-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.4 kB)
> Installing collected packages: hello-pi
> Successfully installed hello-pi-0.0.1

[image]

Is the remote-cache repository in your case not displaying the .pypi directory that indulges the HTML files? If the packages you've cached through the remote repository are publicly available, kindly share a few package examples here.